# How to update 2d array in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to update 2d array but it's not working here. Please check the below code

```
var ksatodayvalue = [];

function pad2(n) { return n < 10 ? '0' + n : n }
var dt = new Date();
currentyear = dt.getFullYear().toString();
currentmonth = pad2(dt.getMonth() + 1);
currentday = pad2(dt.getDate());

   $.getJSON(jsonrequesturl, function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (index, d) {
            ksatodayvalue.push("[Date.UTC("+currentyear+", "+currentmonth+", "+currentday-1+", "+d.time.split(':')[0]+", "+d.time.split(':')[1]+", "+d.time.split(':')[2]+"),3]");
        });
```

**I want array like that.**

```
var ksatodayvalue = [[Date.UTC(2014, 03, 18, 23, 45, 00),3],[Date.UTC(2014, 03, 18, 23, 30, 00),4],[Date.UTC(2014, 03, 18, 23, 15, 00),6],[Date.UTC(2014, 03, 18, 23, 00, 00),8]];
```

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: Also, you're pushing a string not an array... What kind of object is a `Date.UTC(...)`. Your code doesn't make much sense. I think you're confusing a few things here...

Comment: Like elclanrs said, you're just pushing a string into the `ksatodayvalue`.  You need to push an array containing the appropriate objects/numbers.  Also, do you have `currentyear`, `currentmonth`, and `currentday` defined somewhere?

Comment: i'm passing array to highchart..

Answer (score 0):

a) You are creating a string, and probably want an object. b) You probably want values from the incoming data, and not from local variables. Try something along these lines:

```
ksatodayvalue.push([Date.UTC(this.currentyear, this.currentmonth, this.currentday-1, d.time.split(':')[0], d.time.split(':')[1], d.time.split(':')[2]),3]);
```

Comment: it's not working here..showing result like this :- 1397864700000,3,1397863800000,3,1397862900000

Comment: @RohitKhurana Showing where?

Answer (score 0):

```
var ksatodayvalue = [];
$.getJSON(jsonrequesturl, function(data) {
  $.each(data, function(index, d) {
    ksatodayvalue.push([
        Date.UTC(
          this.currentyear,
          this.currentmonth,
          this.currentday-1,
          d.time.split(':')[0],
          d.time.split(':')[1],
          d.time.split(':')[2]
        ), 3
    ]);

  });
}).done(function() {
  console.log(ksatodayvalue);
});
```

Comment: it's not working here..showing result like this :- 1397864700000,3,1397863800000,3

Comment: i need this :- [[Date.UTC(2014, 03, 18, 23, 45, 00),3],[Date.UTC(2014, 03, 18, 23, 30, 00),4],[Date.UTC(2014, 03, 18, 23, 15, 00),6],[Date.UTC(2014, 03, 18, 23, 00, 00),8]];

Comment: You need this as string?

take a look , on Date.UTC function:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC.